# Z80 division algorithm not functioning properly

Tags: math, assembly, z80

I am attempting to run the following code:

```
HLDIVC: 
    LD B,16
D0: XOR A
    ADD HL,HL
    RLA
    CP C
    JR C, D1
    INC L
    SUB C
    DJNZ D0
D1: RET
```

It's an adaptation of the original code: (found [here)](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/math#toc18)

```
HL_Div_C:
;Inputs:
;     HL is the numerator
;     C is the denominator
;Outputs:
;     A is the remainder
;     B is 0
;     C is not changed
;     DE is not changed
;     HL is the quotient
;
       ld b,16
       xor a
         add hl,hl
         rla
         cp c
         jr c,$+4
           inc l
           sub c
         djnz $-7
       ret
```

On an old pocket computer I have. I had to edit the code a little bit, namely because it would seem the assembler on this pocket computer simply does not support the "jr c,$+4" syntax and rather must use labels or absolute addresses. It would seem this may be causing issues, however, because the algorithm does not seem to be working properly. I am calling the function with the following code:

```
ORG O100H
LD HL,20
LD C,10
CALL REGOUT; Display all register values
CALL HLDIVC
CALL REGOUT
RET
```

With this I am trying to divide 20 by 10, so after calling the function the correct value in HL should be 2, and the value in A (The remainder) should be 0, from my understanding. This is not the case, however. Before running the HLDIVC program, these are the register values:

```
| PC = 0107 | AF = 00 44 |
| SP = 7FE8 | BC = 00 0A |    
| IX = 7C06 | DE = 00 14 |    
| IY = 7C0C | HL = 00 14 |
```

(All values are hexadecimal)

After running the program, these are the register values:

```
| PC = 010D | AF = 00 9B | <- A is correct
| SP = 7FE8 | BC = 10 0A | <- B is supposed to be 0
| IX = 7C06 | DE = 00 14 | <- DE is correct
| IY = 7C0C | HL = 00 14 | <- HL should be 2(?)
```

What's going on? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your code is that $+4 and $-7 are both referring to byte counts, not instruction counts, and the JR instruction is 2 bytes.  The indentation gives you a clue.  You need to move your labels:

```
HLDIVC: 
    LD B,16
    XOR A
D0: ADD HL,HL
    RLA
    CP C
    JR C, D1
    INC L
    SUB C
D1: DJNZ D0
    RET
```